# Subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31?

Tags: matlab, octave

When I am executing this function:

```
function generate(x)

  for k=1:257
  x= round(rand*9);
  vet = x*ones(1,16);
  i= round(rand*length(vet));
  val= round(rand*257);
  vet(i)=val
  vet= dec2hex (vet)
  endfor

endfunction
```

I found this error that I don't understand:

```
error: generate: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
error: called from
    generate at line 8 column 9
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I used MATLAB R2015a to replicate the behaviour. The error text is slightly different, but the code essentials are the same as octave*

[`round(something)`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) can generate `0`. When I run your code it hits a `0` every once in a while and crashes with

```
Attempted to access vet(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.
```

because `0` is not a positive integer, nor is it a logical in the case of the other indices being positive integers. To fix it I suggest changing all zeros in `ii` to 1:

```
for k=1:257
  x= round(rand*9);
  vet = x*ones(1,16);
  ii= round(rand*length(vet));
  ii(ii==0)=1;
  val= round(rand*257);
  vet(ii)=val;
  vet= dec2hex (vet);
end % endfor for octave
```

*Note that I changed* `i` *to* `ii`*, as* [`i` *is a built-in function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

An alternative would be to not use `round`, but [`ceil`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html). That way it always round to positive infinity, i.e. it will never hit `0` when using only positive numbers:

```
for k=1:257
  x= round(rand*9);
  vet = x*ones(1,16);
  ii= ceil(rand*length(vet));
  val= round(rand*257);
  vet(ii)=val;
  vet= dec2hex (vet);
end % endfor for octave
```